# Firing event outside class scope javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a class :

```
var psTesting = (function(){

var privatevariable;

function setVariable(value){
    privatevariable = value;
    console.log('the variable value is ' + value);
}

function dismiss ( callback ) {
    console.log('entro dismiss')
    if( callback ) callback();
    if( this.onDismiss ) this.onDismiss();
}

return  {
    pVariable : function(val) {
        setVariable(val)
    }
}
})();

psTesting.pVariable(22);

psTesting.onDismiss = function(){
console.log('this is a onDismiss test');
}
```

I want to be able to fire the onDismiss function from outside of the class `psTesting.onDismiss()`

I have been trying playing with the .call .apply .bind stuff with no luck.

Thanks,
PA

Comment: Are you trying to call `psTesting.onDismiss()`?  Or are you trying to call the internal `dimiss()` function?   `psTesting.onDismiss()` can just be called directly.  The internal `dismiss()` has no external access so it cannot be called.  To call it from the outside you will have to provide public access to it, probably similar to how you define `pVariable`.

Comment: Not a class. `pTesting` is simply an object with a method of `pVariable` and inside `dismiss` function `this` refer to the function not `pTesting`. So `this.onDismiss` is always undefined.

Comment: Return an `onDismiss` method that can take a callback function so that you can store it inside your `pTesting` scope and run it if needed.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do or asking for help with.  Please clarify.

Comment: What I want to accomplish is whenever the dismiss is call inside the psTesting call the onDismiss outside the object

Comment: @jfriend00 i am calling the internal dismiss() and trying to fire the psTesting.onDismiss whenever u call the dismiss function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save a reference internally to the object you are returning so that you can use it to get access to `.onDismiss()` that was added to that object.

```
var psTesting = (function() {

    var privatevariable;

    var obj = {
        pVariable: function(val) {
            setVariable(val)
        }
    }

    function setVariable(value) {
        privatevariable = value;
        console.log('the variable value is ' + value);
    }

    function dismiss(callback) {
        console.log('entro dismiss')
        if (callback) callback();
        if (obj.onDismiss) obj.onDismiss();
    }

    return obj;
})();

psTesting.pVariable(22);

psTesting.onDismiss = function() {
    console.log('this is a onDismiss test');
}
```